# Unit Test: Mocking SpringBootApplication main class with SpringApplication.run

Tags: spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, apache-kafka, mocking

I have been working on this for long and could not figure out a way in mocking the main class in my Spring Boot application (with the code as provided below); without directly calling the actual class in my test class (which I need to avoid).

I've tried with Power Mockito and MockRunner, but doesn't seem to work. How can I proceed?

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaAutoConfiguration;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = KafkaAutoConfiguration.class)
public class KafkaConsumerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(KafkaConsumerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

P.S. I'm furnishing the original test class I've written for the same, which is not appropriate way to test

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = KafkaConsumerApplication.class)
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
public class KafkaConsumerApplicationTest {
    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why would you mock the main entrypoint to the application?

Comment: This is in order to test the application services through the main. Does the traditional approach suffice? Can't we mock it?

Comment: And what is it you want to mock/verify? That java calls the main method? Mocking it doesn’t make sense, as it would yield the app useless as nothing would be started.